# Are there powershell command to manage Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

Are there Powershell commands to manager Azure Devops. I did come across Resp APIs but are there any Powershell commands?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: there is vsteam for example -> https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments of marc_s and D.J. are all helpful. I will summarize their comments here to help community members who get the same issue find the answer more conveniently.
If you want to manage Azure Devops with powershell command ,VSTeam module is a good choice,
VSTeam is a PowerShell module with commands for accessing your azure devops.

1.You need to install VSTeam by using the Install-Module cmdlet.Just make sure on Windows you run PowerShell as administrator and on Mac or Linux you sudo your PowerShell session.  Then simply issue the following command.

```
PS> Install-Module -Name VSTeam
```

2.Once the module is installed you can view all the provided functions by running Get-Command.For details please refer to this [link](https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam).

```
PS>Get-Command -Module VSTeam
```

In addition, you can also use Azure CLI which is available cross platform.
Azure CLI is an extension of azure devops. It allows you to experience Azure DevOps from the command line and work in a streamlined task/command oriented manner without having to worry about the GUI flows.For details please refer to this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-azure-devops-from-the-command-line/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure DevOps CLI - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops which is executable on PowerShell as well.